# Customize the way a Drupal Menu looks like from my Theme

Tags: drupal

I'd like my theme to display a menu in a completely custom way. What functions should I have to use in my theme code? Is there any good tutorial out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, proceed to [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/) and take a look at theme_menu_tree, theme_menu_item, and theme_menu_item_link.  With these overrides, you can change the html that is output by the menu system, and then style accordingly with CSS.

For a tutorial, I would suggest going through the [Drupal 6 theming guide](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6).

You might also want to check out [this article](http://www.palantir.net/blog/better-know-module-menu-block-part-i) from [palantir](http://www.palantir.net), on the menu block module.